# php как заменить несколько методов в классе через файлы?

Tags: php, классы, методы

Суть:
Есть один общий класс, есть табличка с доменами и значениями для них и в зависимости от домена, методы класса должны быть разными.

Сначала думал просто делать include в класс файлы с разными методами, но не прокатило.

Создавать наследников тоже не вариант помоему, потому что нужно что бы это был тот же метод.

Вообщем основной вопрос поменять метод в существующем классе без его переименования?

Пример:
Есть класс:

```
class one
{ 
function say { echo 'hellow';}
}
```

Нужно поменять метод в этом же классе на

```
 function say { echo 'world';}
```

или

```
 function say { echo 'man';}
```

которые должны находиться в отдельных файлах и какой именно файл нужно использовать, определяет табличка.

Вот проблема именно в том как заменить метод в классе

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php Но вообще у вас странный вопрос. Вам не подходит наследование, потому что метод будет иметь тоже название. А потом спрашиваете, как сделать метод без переименования. Можете написать вопрос нормально?

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал написать пример в вопросе

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Answer (score 0):

```
class one
{ 
    function say { echo 'hellow';}
}
```

Можно поменять метод так: (в зависимости от передаваемых данных что бы делал нужное, если по сути делается одно и тоже)

```
class one
{ 
    function say($data = 'hellow') { echo $data;}
}
```

Если нельзя менять старый метод то относледоваться и переопределить метод что бы принимал параметры из вашей таблице

```
class one2 extends one
{ 
    function say($data = 'hellow') { echo $data;}
}
```